# How to connect to a wifi in powershell knowing the SSID and password?

Tags: powershell, wifi

How can I connect to a wifi in powershell just like through GUI but by using code? what commands do I use? I know the SSID and the password.

EDIT: I have never connected to it before so it is a new wifi.

Comment: Scott Hanselman wrote an article about connecting to WiFi through command line: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToConnectToAWirelessWIFINetworkFromTheCommandLineInWindows7.aspx

Comment: Yeah but I want to connect to a new wifi. So I need to enter SSID and PASSWORD.

Answer (score 8):

This isn't Powershell, but it works in every version of 10 so far (currently on 1903).  I have the batch and XML on a flash drive that I run it from. With it in the xml file, I don't have to remember or write down the password/key.

Batch file:

```
Netsh WLAN delete profile "SSID"
Netsh WLAN add profile filename=".\WhateverYouWantToCallIt.XML"
Netsh WLAN connect name="$NAME"
```

WhateverYouWantToCallIt.XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
    <name>SSID_SHOULD_GO_HERE</name>
    <SSIDConfig>
        <SSID>
            <hex>SSID_AS_HEX</hex>
            <name>SSID_SHOULD_GO_HERE</name>
        </SSID>
    </SSIDConfig>
    <connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
    <connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>
    <MSM>
        <security>
            <authEncryption>
                <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>
                <encryption>AES</encryption>
                <useOneX>false</useOneX>
            </authEncryption>
            <sharedKey>
                <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
                <protected>false</protected>
                <keyMaterial>PASSWORD_GOES_HERE</keyMaterial>
            </sharedKey>
        </security>
    </MSM>
    <MacRandomization xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v3">
        <enableRandomization>false</enableRandomization>
    </MacRandomization>
</WLANProfile>
```

Comment: I get "*The network specified by profile is not available to connect*"

Answer (score 6):

```
netsh wlan connect ssid=YOURSSID name=PROFILENAME
```

this should be it...

EDIT: Try this, just worked for me :)

```
netsh wlan connect ssid="YOURSSID" key="YOURPW"
```

Comment: Don't I need to enter the password? I edited my question by the way

Comment: It says "key" is not a valid argument

Comment: I know a very old question but i just tried it again and it says, term "netsh" is not recognized.

Comment: @VadimTatarnikov what version of Windows?

Comment: I got windows 10

Comment: Key is not a command, i really doubt it works for you