# How to write a program to automatically connect to a wifi?

Tags: windows, powershell

Problem: I have to sign in to my client's wifi everyday and it is very troublesome to key in the username and password everyday.

Flow: I would connect to the wifi -network and a web page would pop up to get me to fill up the credentials as stated below.

Sample Credentials:

- Wifi Name: wifi-network
- Password: password123

I have tried to use the Powershell and XML script to connect to the wifi but it does not work. I assume that it is because the wifi password is not stated in the XML script. Is that the reason?

XML Script

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
    <name>nlt_guest</name>
    <SSIDConfig>
        <SSID>
            <hex>6E6C745F6775657374</hex>
            <name>wifi-network</name>
        </SSID>
    </SSIDConfig>
    <connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
    <connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>
    <MSM>
        <security>
            <authEncryption>
                <authentication>open</authentication>
                <encryption>none</encryption>
                <useOneX>false</useOneX>
            </authEncryption>
        </security>
    </MSM>
    <MacRandomization xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v3">
        <enableRandomization>false</enableRandomization>
        <randomizationSeed>610328332</randomizationSeed>
    </MacRandomization>
</WLANProfile>
```

Powershell Script

```
netsh wlan add profile filename="$PSScriptRoot\Wi-Fi-nlt_guest.xml
```

Comment: What version of windows? Normally it just connects automatically after you connect the _first_ time. I've never had to type a WiFi password in more than once.

Comment: I am using Windows 10. It's a wifi that is set up by my client and when we connect to the wifi, a webpage will pop up and we will key in the credentials accordingly (just like the Starbucks wifi).

Comment: Deleted the XML tag - this is not a question about XML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to a wifi in powershell knowing the SSID and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32760356/how-to-connect-to-a-wifi-in-powershell-knowing-the-ssid-and-password)